# improve performance of custom CartoDB layer visualization with join

Tags: javascript, cartodb

I am fairly new to CartoDB (which is awesome, btw) and using CartoDB.js to build a custom visualization but the solution I have is quite slow on initial load (takes ~1 minute plus to load), which based on the documentation [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tips-and-tricks.html#common-table-expression) I believe is a result of using CTE in my SQL (which I confirmed on their GUI for this map: http://cdb.io/1hL3pzF, **much** faster without CTE); however I have not seen reference to another approach - does anyone have a good solution for this?

I assume there is a default name assigned to the query (eg in the cartodb.com GUI the associate CartoCSS uses whatever table you started with...) but have not seen reference yet.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crshunter/v0q8egbm/18/) of my working approach, also here:

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS

```
#map { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 3px; height: 400px; width: 600px; }
```

JS

```
    var map = new L.map('map');

/* this works but is quite slow...
what is result of query called from cartodb?
*/
var cartocss = '#summary_tbl{ polygon-fill: #F1EEF6; polygon-opacity: 0.8; line-color: #FFF; line-width: 0.5; line-opacity: 1;}';
cartocss = cartocss + '#summary_tbl [ methane <= 158.47731712611244] { polygon-fill: #91003F; }';
    cartocss = cartocss + '#summary_tbl [ methane <= 135] { polygon-fill: #CE1256; }';
    cartocss = cartocss + '#summary_tbl [ methane <= 120.95519348268839] { polygon-fill: #E7298A; }';
    cartocss = cartocss + '#summary_tbl [ methane <= 112.3529411764706] { polygon-fill: #DF65B0; }';
    cartocss = cartocss + '#summary_tbl [ methane <= 108.42857142857143] { polygon-fill: #C994C7; }';
    cartocss = cartocss + '#summary_tbl [ methane <= 104.09859154929578] { polygon-fill: #D4B9DA; }';
    cartocss = cartocss + '#summary_tbl [ methane <= 98.36206896551724] { polygon-fill: #F1EEF6; }';

var sql_summ = "WITH summary_tbl AS (SELECT avg(n.methane) as methane, count(n.cartodb_id) record_count, h.the_geom_webmercator ";
    sql_summ = sql_summ + "FROM nurve_sample_boston_0828 n JOIN hex_base_v500m h ON ST_Within(n.the_geom, h.the_geom) ";
    sql_summ = sql_summ + "GROUP BY h.the_geom_webmercator) SELECT methane, the_geom_webmercator FROM summary_tbl";

var cbd_layer = {
  user_name: 'crshunter', // Required
  type: 'cartodb', // Required
  sublayers: [{
    sql: sql_summ,
    cartocss: cartocss, // Required
    interactivity: "methane"
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    map.on('load', function(e){
        // grab OSM basemap for context
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
        cartodb.createLayer(map, cbd_layer).addTo(map);
    });
});

var startPosition = new L.LatLng(42.3601, -71.0589); // Boston, MA
map.setView(startPosition, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case helpful for anyone, a much better approach has been to move this function to the backend using the [cartodb-nodejs](https://github.com/Vizzuality/cartodb-nodejs) library - silly of me not to do that from the beginning really.